# how to query to get the user from m2m relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a model for forum. Its just the basics, and I am trying the grasp the relationship and how to query with them. So, I have a forum with field for question, body, published date, image, and likes. I guess my model design is correct, if not please correct me. So, everything is works as I wanted. Just that, how do I get all the Users who liked the forum and count the likes? How can i query it? Please guide me through.
Thank you.

models.py:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator_set")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Like")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Like(models.Model):
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    liked = models.ForeignKey(User)
    liked_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s likes %s" % (self.liked, self.forum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this suppose to work?:

```
Forum.objects.get(pk=1).likes.all()
Forum.objects.get(pk=1).likes.count()
```

Comment: You don't.. you need to save it to template context inside the view.